# Using ideal image slider but just leaves images on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, bower-install

I am having an issue getting [this](https://github.com/Codeinwp/Ideal-Image-Slider-JS) slider to work. I started with bower install. I am including the css and default in the header, and javascript in the body, and then I added some js of my own to load the slider in, but it keeps just showing the images on the screen without building the slider. I know it must be a loading issue, but I keep trying to load the js after everything else, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is a sample file I created just to test it out without any of my other website code around.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link href="./bower_components/ideal-image-slider/ideal-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="./bower_components/ideal-image-slider/themes/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="./bower_components/ideal-image-slider/ideal-image-slider.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
                var slider = new IdealImageSlider.Slider({
                    selector: '#slider',
                    height: 400, // Required but can be set by CSS
                    interval: 4000
                });
                slider.start();
                console.log("slideshow hit");
            })();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slider">
            <img src="./src/images/rotate/img01.JPG" alt="Minimum required attributes">
            <img src="./src/images/rotate/img02.JPG" alt="Use data-src for on-demand loading">
            <img src="./src/images/rotate/img03.JPG" alt="Use data-src for on-demand loading">
            <img src="./src/images/rotate/img04.JPG" alt="Use data-src for on-demand loading">
            <img src="./src/images/rotate/img05.JPG" alt="Use data-src for on-demand loading">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know it is going to be a simple change, but I just don't see it now. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this bloc

```
<img src="./src/images/rotate/img01.JPG" alt="Minimum required attributes">
<img src="./src/images/rotate/img02.JPG" alt="Use data-src for on-demand loading">
<img src="./src/images/rotate/img03.JPG" alt="Use data-src for on-demand loading">
<img src="./src/images/rotate/img04.JPG" alt="Use data-src for on-demand loading">
<img src="./src/images/rotate/img05.JPG" alt="Use data-src for on-demand loading">
```

by this

```
<img src="./src/images/rotate/img01.JPG" alt="slide 1">
<img data-src="./src/images/rotate/img02.JPG" alt="slide 2" src="">
<img data-src="./src/images/rotate/img03.JPG" alt="slide 3" src="">
<img data-src="./src/images/rotate/img04.JPG" alt="slade 4" src="">
<img data-src="./src/images/rotate/img05.JPG" alt="slide 5" src="">
```

Comment: this just puts boxes around the alt text instead of showing an image. It is still just showing the first image and alt text inline after it. Still means the js is not getting read in the right order. Not sure why. I am using wamp server, and everything seems to be running properly. But I have an order of operations not working for rendering the js.

Answer (score 0):

I found these two script tags at the end of the body did the trick.

```
<script src="./bower_components/ideal-image-slider/ideal-image-slider.min.js"></script>

<script>
    new IdealImageSlider.Slider({
        selector: '#slider',
        height: 400
    });
</script>
```

I had the js loading at the wrong place like I suspected. Thanks all.